# How to remove duplicate data from array on basis of 2 key-value combination in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
{
    "product": [{
        "IDs": ["00000087102110"],
        "Brand": "SONY",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "SONY",
        "Year": "2020",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "SAMSUNG",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 2
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102150"],
        "Brand": "HCL",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102110"],
        "Brand": "LG",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 3
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "LENOVO",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "LENOVO",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "LENOVO",
        "Year": "2020",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102150"],
        "Brand": "HP",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 3
    }],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

I want to make so if `Brand` and `Rank` are equal then I want to keep only last data for that `Brand` and `Rank`.

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "product": [{
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "SONY",
        "Year": "2020",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "SAMSUNG",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 2
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102150"],
        "Brand": "HCL",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102110"],
        "Brand": "LG",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 3
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "LENOVO",
        "Year": "2020",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102150"],
        "Brand": "HP",
        "Year": "2019",
        "Rank": 3
    }],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

I tried below code but it is not giving expected result. So how to get above expect output? Please advise.

```
$json_arr = json_decode($result, true);

$index = array();
foreach ($json_arr as $key1 => $level1)
{
    foreach ($level1 as $key2 => $level2)
    {
        if (isset($index[$level2['Brand']]) && isset($index[$level2['Rank']]))     
        {
            unset($level2[$key]);
        }
        $index[$level2['Brand']] = TRUE;
        $index[$level2['Rank']] = TRUE;
    }        
}
```

EDIT : I tried `array_unqiue` function but I think it is not working in multi level array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next code as solution:

```
$json_arr = json_decode($result, true);

// loop throw product array
foreach ($json_arr['product'] as $p) {
    // add product to array by key composed from `Brand` and `Rank`
    // in case duplicate same `Brand` & `Rank` pair the value will be rewriten
    // so, after loop we will get last values for each pair
    $res["$p[Brand]_$p[Rank]"] = $p;
}

$json_arr['product'] = array_values($res);

print_r($json_arr);
```

Working code example here [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=bc471c1bc82af3c7eb9456662b07bdba&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: What should I do if I want first duplicate record instead of last one?

Comment: Just change `$res["$p[Brand]_$p[Rank]"] = $p;` to 
`if (!isset($res["$p[Brand]_$p[Rank]"]))    $res["$p[Brand]_$p[Rank]"] = $p;` like here: https://phpize.online/?phpses=40b051d297e6c322150808d90e850922&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80